# Send to non Drupal 404 for path in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I have a Drupal 8 site and I want to send a certain path to hit a non Drupal 404 (Don't want it to hit Drupal at all so nothing is logged). For example: `autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`. I tried the following:

I tried the following 3 things in .htaccess but they did not work:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI ".*autodiscover/autodiscover.xml" "id:9990001,nolog,status:404,chain"
SecRule SERVER_NAME "mysite\.com" "t:lowercase"
```

```
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml?$ - [R=404,NC,L]
```

```
ErrorDocument 404 autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004553253-Avoiding-404-error-messages-in-your-logs

Comment: When I use composer to update core, .htaccess get's overwritten and the rewrite rule will be erased. What do you guys do to avoid that?

Comment: @MetalBearSolid Check out https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290989/composer-keeps-overwriting-htaccess-and-other-files-every-time-i-do-anything